# How can I determine where a workflow is getting manager information from?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server, email

I'm attempting to determine where the following workflow is getting a submitting user's manager's email address from:

[image: Workflow in question]

It doesn't appear to be coming out of Active Directory as when I try to submit a form, it goes to my former manager who is no longer with the company; my account in AD shows my current manager.

I'm not terribly familiar with Sharepoint Designer and the fellow who designed this workflow is also no longer with the company...

Thank you!

Comment: what about the user profile service, who is listed as manager in your profile.

Comment: How do I check that?

Comment: you can click the name of user in sharepoint...

Comment: Ah okay, that is showing my manager as the old manager. Where does that information come from?

Comment: what sharepoint version you are using? looks like your User Profile Services is not working.?

Comment: 2010. I checked the services on the server and the User Profile Service is running...

Comment: What about the User profile sync service? on the same page next to user profile service....also cenral admin> application managment > manage service application> click on User profile service > check when last tume sync run

Comment: I am trying to run a manual sync now. The User Profile Sync service was not running. Attempting to start it has resulted in it being stuck in a "Starting" state.

Comment: Ah, it just took a long time. That service is started now.

Comment: And, sorry, the information about my manager, even after a manual sync, is still incorrect.

Comment: Did you run the full sync?

Comment: Just an incremental. I just ran a full, and that has now corrected the issue.

Comment: Is it solve your solve issue?

Comment: I modified my answer as per ur issue. Please mark that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information pulled by the user profile. You have to check if user profile service configured and sync is working. Please run a full synv and then try again.

You can pull the data from the user profile.

something like this:

[image][image][image]

please check [this blog for more information](http://www.sharepointanalysthq.com/2011/04/user-profile-data-in-sharepoint-designer-workflows/)